# Why add user to custom audience php api sdk call is considered as FILE_IMPORTED HASHES_OR_USER_IDS

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-marketing-api

I am creating custom audience using following code.

```
$audience = new CustomAudience(null, $accountId);
$audience->setData(array(
          CustomAudienceFields::NAME            => $associative_arr['name'],
          CustomAudienceFields::PIXEL_ID        => $associative_arr['pixelId'],
          CustomAudienceFields::DESCRIPTION     => $associative_arr['description'],
          CustomAudienceFields::RETENTION_DAYS  => $associative_arr['retensionDays'],  
          CustomAudienceFields::SUBTYPE         => CustomAudienceSubtypes::WEBSITE,
          CustomAudienceFields::RULE            => array('url' => array('i_contains' => $associative_arr['websiteUrl'])),
          CustomAudienceFields::PREFILL         => $associative_arr['prefill'],
          CustomAudienceFields::DATA_SOURCE     => array('EVENT_BASED' => 'WEB_PIXEL_HITS')
        ));         
$audience->create();
```

After that I am using code from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/custom-audience-api/v2.8 to add user in custom audience but getting following error

```
Uncaught exception 'FacebookAds\Http\Exception\AuthorizationException' with message '(#2650) Failed to update the custom audience: This audience was created from data source EVENT_BASED.WEB_PIXEL_HITS, which does not support data source FILE_IMPORTED.HASHES_OR_USER_IDS
```

Any suggestions how I can solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom audience from a Website Traffic(Pixel), App Engagement, Customer file or Engagement on Fb. If you create an audience from Website traffic (Pixel), you can't add user's to the audience like you can when creating the audience from customer file.